# Issues with strings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, replace, c-strings

I have a snippet of code that takes the output of another function (that function gets user input) and replaces all spaces with dashes. Or, rather, that's what it's supposed to do. Instead, it takes the first word of the string and ignores the rest (e.g. 'Hello World' -> 'Hello'). Here is the snippet:

```
void info::name(string* name, string title){
    char arr[title.size() + 1];
    strcpy(arr, title.c_str());
    int o = 0;
    while(arr[o] != 0){
        if(arr[o] == ' '){
            arr[o] = '-';
        };
        o++;
    };
    *name = arr;
```

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

EDIT: What do you mean by combining C-style arrays and `std::string`?

EDIT2: I tried using std::replace, but the same thing happens.

EDIT3: I can't get getline() to work. Here is how I'm using it:

```
getline(cin, *title, "/n");
```

Why is *this* not working?

FINAL_EDIT: I finally got it to work! Here is what worked for me:

```
void info::title(string* title){
    cout << "Enter the name of your mod: ";
    getline(cin, *title); cout << endl;}
void info::name(string* name, string title){
    replace(title.begin(), title.end(), ' ', '-');
    *name = title;}
```

Once again, thanks, all!

Comment: there are a lot of reasons why this wouldn't work actually!!

Comment: @Creep2DJ  This declaration char arr[title.size() + 1]; is invalid in C++ .:)

Comment: TL;DR [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  I did that this morning and it worked on C++. Not in C I agree. you can define dynamic-sized arrays on the stack all right in C++.

Comment: `string *name(title);` should be a compiler error.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No, Variable length arrays are illegal in c++, it will work in c though.

Comment: @Creep2DJ  Also check whether title is indeed contains moew than one word. Perhaps you entered data using the operator >> instead of the function getline.

Comment: You should do some debugging (or just follow @juanchopanza's suggestion).

Comment: @Ben: compiled a lot of them using g++ 4.9.x, Worked fine.Should fail with compilation error? I thought that was the contrary: can't do in C.

Comment: Why, oh why are you mixing C-style strings, and `std::string`. I feel like jumping off  a cliff reading this code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: don't. Just downvote.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre agreed....

Comment: @Ben: could it be that g++ doesn't care of what is legal and accepts it since it technically can accept it? (ok we should use vectors, but what if the code is already crap and we try to fix it cheaply ? :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But it is technically incorrect: The C++ standard states that array size must be a constant expression (8.3.4.1). Are you sure in the compilations you did you were not using say `sizeof(someType)` in the array or similar?

Comment: *EDIT: What do you mean by combining C-style arrays and std::string?* -- So to the OP:  Do you want an actual C++ solution, or stick with `C` code?  In `C++`, the real solution is to use (already mentioned) `std::replace` or some other algorithm(s), and just drop using the code you've written.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `-pedantic -Werror` or it doesn't count.

Comment: One reason why it wouldn't work is you replacing all the spaces with dashes in the variable `arr`, and then forget about it completely, throw `arr` away and never use it.  There might be other reasons but this one is pretty big. You probably would catch it in less than a minute if you used a debugger.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't c/p it in, this was an error in this snippet only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the effect you want can be achieved.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct A
{
    static std::string name( const std::string &title )
    {
        std::string result;
        result.reserve( title.size() );

        std::replace_copy_if( title.begin(), title.end(),
                              std::back_inserter( result ),
                              []( char c ) { return c == ' '; }, '-' );

        return result;                            
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::string title;
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Enter a title: ";

    if ( std::getline( std::cin, title ) ) name = A::name( title );

    std::cout << name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter string `"Hello World"`

then the output will look like

```
Enter a title: Hello World
Hello-World
```

I used the standard algorithm `std::replace_copy_if` only to show how to use lambda expressions. For example you could substitute also the tab character for the dash.

```
std::replace_copy_if( title.begin(), title.end(),
                      std::back_inserter( result ),
                      []( char c ) { return c == ' ' || c == '\t'; }, '-' );
```

Otherwise you can use standard algorithm `std::replace_copy` the following way

```
std::replace_copy( title.begin(), title.end(),
                   std::back_inserter( result ),
                   ' ', '-' );
```

As you see the task can be done without using an intermediate array. Moreover this declaration of an array

```
char arr[title.size() + 1];
```

is not C++ compliant declaration though some compilers can have their own extensions that allow such declarations..

Also there is a typo in your function. I think you mean

```
*name = arr;
```

instead of

```
*name = title;
```

Comment: that's -1 for replying to this bad question, +2 for showing off on C++ STL stuff & other subtleties I did not know :)

Comment: How come you're using a variable address in the function definition instead of a pointer?

Comment: @Creep2DJ -- That is not an address.  The `&` in this context means `reference`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

Yes you create temporary array, modify it and then assign unmodified original string to string pointed by first argument.

You do not need temporary array at all and passing a pointer is not a C++ way to do it:

```
std::string info::name( std::string title )
{
    std::replace( title.begin(), title.end(), ' ', '-' );
    return title;
}
```

if you do want to use loop (required by homework etc) just do it on string itself:

```
std::string info::name( std::string title )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < title.length(); ++i ) {
        if( title[i] == ' ' )
            title[i] = '-';
    }
    return title;
}
```